# Changing the tint of the iOS UITextField clear button in iOS 11

Tags: uitextfield, ios11

In iOS 10 we changed the tint of our UITextField clear buttons using the following KVO approach.

```
let clearButton = registrationTextField.value(forKey: "_clearButton") as! UIButton

if let clearImage = clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) {
        clearButton.setImage(clearImage, for: UIControlState())
        clearButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

However, with the introduction of iOS 11 `clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` now returns nil.

More specifically `clearButton.imageView?.image` returns nil.

Are there alternative ways of accessing the image now?